# Castle IInterceptorSelector and Implementation Type Method

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, aop, interceptor

Hi I have created an Interceptor for Retry Support and I mark methods with a RetryAttribute.

I have implemented an IInterceptorSelector to only return the Interceptor if the type has a method with that custom attribute.

In the RetryInterceptor class I look for that attribute on the method provided by the invocation and if it exists I run the retry logic.

I was hoping to have the IInterceptorSelector filter the set of interceptors on a method basis but the method passed in is other the interface type not the actual class implementing it. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some code outlining the issue please?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check for the method info from the type using the interface method info:

```
public class Selector : IInterceptorSelector
{
    public IInterceptor[] SelectInterceptors(Type type, MethodInfo method, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
    {
        var attributes = type.GetMethod(method.Name).GetCustomAttributes(false);
        if (attributes.OfType<Retry>().Any())
        {
            // return retry interceptor
        }
        else
        {
            // return no interceptor
        }
    }
}
```